# Save NSData when memory mapped

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

What I am hoping to do may or may not be possible but I'll give it a shot. I am attempting to load huge multiple gigabyte text files. I am currently using an memory mapped NSData and only loading portions at a time and just infinite scrolling through it and load the currently visible chunk and it all is happy and it barely breaks a sweat with memory (<30mb).

Next I wanted to add editing of the data. I casually assumed I could just edit that memory mapped data and have it reflect on disk. This does not seem to be the case. Is there a way I can say hey the data changed! update the file. I am a little vague on how the file and NSData are linked.

Here is how it is currently working.

```
// create the memory mapped data:
self.fileData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:outError];

//load a chunk
self.currentRange = NSMakeRange(0, 4096);
void* data = malloc(4096);
[self.fileData getBytes:data range:self.currentRange];
NSString* currentView = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data length:4096 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//replace a chunk:
NSData* currentData = [[self.textArea string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self.fileData replaceBytesInRange:self.currentRange withBytes:[currentData bytes] length:[currentData length]];
//If I close and re-open it doesn't actually work
```

Is there a way of doing this or would it be possible to create an `NSOutputStream` to the URL and somehow stream portions of it back to disk? Is there another way to write/save memory mapped data? If I try to do a `writeToURL:` or comparable function it will load it all to actual memory which is really no good.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Comment: I spent some time looking into it and trying various things. I never found a solution I was happy with.

Comment: You could [see how HexFiend handles this](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/HexFiend), which is designed to view and edit files ‘as large as 118 GB’.